# Composition and linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $T: V \to V$ and $S:V \to V$ are non-null linear transformations such that $T \circ S=0$, then $T$ is not injective.

Comment: Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Not yet, must I admit.

Comment: Well, the question concerns vector spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch of proof:

Because $S$ is non-null, there should be two vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$ in $V$ s.t. $S(u_1) \ne S(u_2)$.

If $T$ were injective then $T(w_1) = T(w_2) \implies w_1 =w_2$ for *every* $w_1$ and $w_2$ in $V$.

But if we let $w_1 = S(u_1)$ and $w_2 = S(u_2)$ then we can see that clearly this does not hold.  So $T$ is not injective.

Comment: I did not understand why you say that w1=S(u1).

Comment: Because $(T\circ S)(u_1) = T(S(u_1)) = T(S(u_2)) = (T\circ S)(u_2) = 0$, but $S(u_1) \ne S(u_2)$.

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. Thanks.